Do I have to bother with isolation?
I am currently designing a device which is intended to communicate with different devices over RS232. The communication targets are mainly network switches from different manufacturers. The distance between the two devices is limited to around 2m.
My board will be mounted in a metal case with some other I/O interfaces such as Ethernet and USB.
When planning the rough layout of the device I stumbled across the isolation distances and recognized that it would be easy so implement them on the board, but the distance between the shielded connectors of my RS232 section and the metal chassis would definitely fall short of the required clearance distance. Adding a plastic section to the chassis is no option.
My chassis will be tied to earth via the mains cord.
Looking at other commercial devices in the networking sector with RS232 interfaces: Most of them do not seem to be implemented fully isolated. Their chassis are also earthed via the mains cord.
To avoid overthinking my clearance problem:
Do I have to bother with implementing a fully isolated RS232 interface on my board or is a non-isolated RS232 interface sufficient?

So how resilient is your device to stray electromagnetic interference / signals? If it will be guaranteed  error free then you have no issues. BUT if your device is susceptible to errors due to other signals and it turns off your pacemaker then you might be concerned ... or not as someone said it's only half a day with the undertaker.

@Burglups The connected devices will be in close proximity to each other. But there is no guarantee that the enduser will mount both devices in the same rack. Even though it is the intended purpose of my device to be mounted next to the network switch.

We don't know what you are ecpecting. Generally, if you used a desktop PC, it will have the DE-9 shell tied to chassis and it will have common system ground tied to chassis, and the chassis is earthed via mains cord. Perhaps if you explained why you think you need isolation would be helpful, do you expect e.g. tens or hundreds of mandatory potential difference between two RS-232 devices, or do you expect them to be both at earth potential, or would any of the devices have a floating supply? Is your device earthed, directly or via power supply mains cord?

I clarified the earth connections above. Both devices are expected to be correctly connected to earth.
I do not expect large differences in the ground potential between my device and the target device.

If the two devices (a) have no real potential difference and (b) you don't need to avoid ground loops, what more reasons you might have left for isolation? Most network devices get their chassises connected together via Ethernet cable shield anyway so why not via RS232 ground and shield too?

The only scenario in which isolation makes sense is if you want an "idiot proof" connection since you suspect that the person who connects the other end of the cable might mix up signals with 24V supply or something like that.

@Justme Hmm, "most" seems like significantly understating the popularity of UTP Ethernet?

@TimWilliams Ethernet is a tranaformer coupled and galvanically isolated interface. At what potential do you suppose the data wires float at? Transformers also are required for 1000VAC isolation.

@Justme No I mean, you indicated shielded Ethernet which is not just floating wires but a very specifically earthed shield tying things together; a very different situation than the isolated wires alone! I can say for my part at least, none of my network devices share an earth connection through their (UTP not STP) Ethernet cabling (and indeed several devices do not even have an earth connection).

@TimWilliams So you don't have a desktop PC or laptop? Or desktop PC not grounded? Infrastructure cabling inside walls not shielded, and that shield not bonded to earth like in normal buildings? Anyway, that's the point - Ethernet data wires are isolated, devices will connect to shield as best seen fit, or don't connect if best fit. But likely STP shield connects tightly to earth via your PC. And it's perfectly OK to use shielded or unshielded cables between any devices.

@Justme Devices that are not themselves grounded, I mean. There are and aren't grounds in the system. Since I don't have STP, ungrounded devices are not, in turn, being grounded by those that are.

@TimWilliams And Ethernet data lines are still isolated regardless, and don't care if there is few hundred volts between cable and device. People connect grounded and ungrounded devices together daily, TVs, monitors, computers, laptops, audio systems, and not one of them need isolation. MIDI is most common isolated interface after Ethernet and it isolates due to ground loops possibly causing hum in the audio connections, so that's why it isolates. For RS-232 between devices, there is really no evidence that it must be isolated in this case.

If all your devices are hard-wired to the same supply ground, then isolation is almost certainly not necessary.
If all your devices plug into the same ground, then isolation is probably not necessary, if you can ensure they are all connected to earth before you connect the RS232 leads.
If the other devices are not connected to ground, and especially if they are connected to other random things by their comms leads, then isolation is probably a good idea. If they are small, and connected via isolating supplies, and not connected outside their system by other leads, then you may well get away without.
If the interfaces connect to things in other buildings, or other systems like the telephone network, then isolation is mandatory. Note that ethernet is isolated by default.
Any particular interface might survive indefinitely if its internal protection is sufficient for any small abuse you subject it to through its ports.
The worst case is where your test and development systems work in the lab, and then fail when they get to the customer.

Hard-wired: Negativ. All devices have independent power cords and are powered from regular mains voltage with their own internal PSUs.
Order of connection (first power or first RS232 cable) is out of my control as it is up to the enduser.
Ground connection of the other devices: It is up to them to follow the applicable regulations.
The connection is definitely limited to devices in close proximity (2m range).

Some additional explanation may be illuminating here -- the primary reason for grounded equipment is because the RS-232 connector (presumably, the D-sub types as defined in EIA-232-D or TIA-574) contains exposed metal, which therefore must be either grounded or double-insulated for protection to users; and preferably has at least one earth path somewhere to deal with possible cross-wiring faults. Of those two cases, the one (grounding) is mentioned, but it's worth mentioning the other case.

Non-mains powered equipment can use these connectors as well (there's no reason to earth a battery-powered device, for example, but one can easily use these connectors all the same).

@TimWilliams I stand by the 3rd paragraph with things not connected to ground. They can accumulate damaging charges if not otherwise handled.

Hmm, so you're just concerned about ESD hazard on plugging? (Perhaps more robust than HBM, charged cable model for example.) That should be easily handled by an ESD-rated interface though (or at worst, added TVSs), and grounding isn't a required solution (e.g. large-value resistance can drain such charge). Does that mean it's not an operating (e.g. causes bit errors) concern, then?

@TimWilliams 'just' is a 4-letter word

Oh. Well then do you have a better way to ask a specific clarifying question? Because apparently I'm terrible at them. (Which isn't too surprising, to be fair. Communication is difficult.)

@Neil_UK "Work" is a 4 letter word...

Typically no, like you said RS232 distances are short. I have isolated RS232 but for a different reason, I had a sensitive analog board and I wanted to avoid any kind of ground loop.
So if you need to break a ground loop, then use isolation, if not then it doesn't matter. Look at cost.

If you look at a desktop PC from a few years ago - the sort that came with RS232 ports as standard - then they made no attempt to isolate the RS232 outputs.
The 9 or 25 way D-type connector would have its shell connected to chassis of the computer.  The ground pin on the connector would go to the motherboard ground, which in turn would be connected to the chassis, possibly through the power supply.
The expectation was that the act of plugging in the connector would equalise the ground voltages at each end, through the lead.
